# How to add a key:pair value to a nested dictionary, mapped to an item

Tags: ansible

There is a high chance I've vastly overcomplicated this, however, I've stared at it for so long I'm struggling to work around it. I'm looking to add a {key: pair} from a list of dictionaries, into a separate dictionary, where the new {key: pair} maps to an item within a list, within the new dictionary. Hopefully, the example will explain this better than I am able to.

I have the following variables, a main dictionary, called db_dict. A variable called container_db mapped to the db_dict.key that I want to alter. A list of values, pdb which maps to whichever item in *db_dict.CORCL.pdbs* we are editing and latest_success, which I want to add to *db_dict.CORCL.pdbs* mapped to the relevant pdb

```yaml
    db_dict:
      CORCL:
        job_queue_processes_pre: 80
        latest_failure: ''
        latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.0
        pdbs:
        - PDB$SEED
        - ORCL
        - ORCL2
        status: running
        sysaux_free_mb: 3677
        system_free_mb: 4513
        type: multitenant

    container_db: CORCL

    seed_latest_success_list:
      - latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
        pdb: PDB$SEED
      - latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
        pdb: ORCL
      - latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
        pdb: ORCL2
```

I have tried the following with limited success:

```yaml
    - name: Update db_dict with latest_success
      set_fact:
        db_dict: "{{ db_dict | combine({ container_db: db_dict[container_db] | combine({ 'pdbs': db_dict[container_db].pdbs | default([]) | map('combine', item) | list }) }) }}"
      loop: "{{ seed_latest_success_list }}"
```

Have I just vastly over/under complicated this idea I had in my head, is anyone able to help before I go completely mad?

Expected result should look something like this:

```yaml
    db_dict:
      CORCL:
        job_queue_processes_pre: 80
        latest_failure: ''
        latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.0
        pdbs:
          PDB$SEED:
            latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
          ORCL:
            latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
          ORCL2:
            latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
        status: running
        sysaux_free_mb: 3677
        system_free_mb: 4513
        type: multitenant
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: updated with expected result, i'm not too precious about how it should look however, so if their is a better solution i'm all ears

Comment: `seed_latest_success_list` indicates there might be more items in the list. What should happen with additional items on this list?

Comment: May `CORCL.latest_success` and `CORCL.pdbs.*.latest_success` be different?

Comment: Should all `CORCL.pdbs.*.latest_success` be the same?

Comment: You update all items in `pdbs`. What is the purpose of `pdb: PDB$SEED`?

Comment: seed_latest_success_list could be as long as the limit of pdbs in oracle, so a large number of items.

yes, CORCL.latest_success and the pdbs.latest_success could be different

pdbs.latest_success could all be different

Comment: i can easily remove pdb: PDB$SEED from the seed_latest_success, i just initially thought it would be helpful to map the value of latest_success

Comment: I updated *seed_latest_success_list* and the expected result. Is this a valid scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the list *seed_latest_success_list* to a dictionary

```yaml
  seed_latest_success_dict: "{{ dict(seed_latest_success_list|
                                     json_query('[].[pdb, @]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  seed_latest_success_dict:
    ORCL:
      latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
      pdb: ORCL
    ORCL2:
      latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
      pdb: ORCL2
    PDB$SEED:
      latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
      pdb: PDB$SEED
```

Get the *pdbs* keys and values, and create *db_dict_update*

```yaml
  pdbs_keys: "{{ db_dict[container_db].pdbs }}"
  pdbs_vals: "{{ pdbs_keys|map('extract', seed_latest_success_dict) }}"
  db_dict_update: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {{ container_db }}:
      pdbs: {{ dict(pdbs_keys|zip(pdbs_vals)) }}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  pdbs_keys:
    - PDB$SEED
    - ORCL
    - ORCL2

  pdbs_vals:
    - {latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1, pdb: PDB$SEED}
    - {latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2, pdb: ORCL}
    - {latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3, pdb: ORCL2}

  db_dict_update:
    CORCL:
      pdbs:
        ORCL:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
          pdb: ORCL
        ORCL2:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
          pdb: ORCL2
        PDB$SEED:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
          pdb: PDB$SEED
```

---

Notes:

- Optionally, create the dictionary in a single template. The expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  db_dict_update: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {{ container_db }}:
      pdbs:
    {% for pdb in db_dict[container_db].pdbs %}
        {{ pdb }}: {{ seed_latest_success_dict[pdb] }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

- Optionally, remove *pdb* attribute

```yaml
  pdbs_vals: "{{ pdbs_keys|map('extract', seed_latest_success_dict)|
                           ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['pdb']) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  pdbs_vals:
    - {latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1}
    - {latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2}
    - {latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3}

  db_dict_update:
    CORCL:
      pdbs:
        ORCL:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
        ORCL2:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
        PDB$SEED:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
```

---

Update the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        db_dict: "{{ db_dict|
                     combine(db_dict_update, recursive=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  db_dict:
    CORCL:
      job_queue_processes_pre: 80
      latest_failure: ''
      latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.0
      pdbs:
        ORCL:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
          pdb: ORCL
        ORCL2:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
          pdb: ORCL2
        PDB$SEED:
          latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
          pdb: PDB$SEED
      status: running
      sysaux_free_mb: 3677
      system_free_mb: 4513
      type: multitenant
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    db_dict:
      CORCL:
        job_queue_processes_pre: 80
        latest_failure: ''
        latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.0
        pdbs:
        - PDB$SEED
        - ORCL
        - ORCL2
        status: running
        sysaux_free_mb: 3677
        system_free_mb: 4513
        type: multitenant

    container_db: CORCL
    seed_latest_success_list:
      - latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.1
        pdb: PDB$SEED
      - latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.2
        pdb: ORCL
      - latest_success: DATAPUMP BUNDLE PATCH 19.19.0.0.3
        pdb: ORCL2

    seed_latest_success_dict: "{{ dict(seed_latest_success_list|
                                       json_query('[].[pdb, @]')) }}"
    pdbs_keys: "{{ db_dict[container_db].pdbs }}"
    pdbs_vals: "{{ pdbs_keys|map('extract', seed_latest_success_dict) }}"
    db_dict_update: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {{ container_db }}:
        pdbs: {{ dict(pdbs_keys|zip(pdbs_vals)) }}
      {% endfilter %}
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: seed_latest_success_dict
    - debug:
        var: pdbs_keys
    - debug:
        var: pdbs_vals|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: db_dict_update

    - set_fact:
        db_dict: "{{ db_dict|
                     combine(db_dict_update, recursive=true) }}"
    - debug:
        var: db_dict
```

Comment: blimey, well done, and thank you, thats a massive help - hadn't even considered trying jinja. This makes life a lot lot easier